# Glitch in viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, picasso

I have made a view pager slider which slider layout. I have added parallax like transformation to it.

Code:

```
viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager.setPadding(64, 0, 64, 0);
    viewPager.setPageMargin(24);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(@NonNull View view, float v) {
            if (v >= -1 && v <= 1) {
                view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_backdrop).setTranslationX(-v*(viewPager.getWidth()/2));
            } else {
                view.setAlpha(1);
            }
        }
    });
```

And the layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_backdrop"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:scaleX="1.2"
    android:scaleY="1.2"
    android:src="@drawable/musical"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView_overlay"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imageView_overlay"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_overlay" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_overlay"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_rounded_rectangle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<...>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have made the imageview to scale 1.2 because the parallax would give me empty edges on swiping.

But the Images are not fitting inside their layout, and overflowing.

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself! I had to set cropToPadding as true for the overflowing imageView.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_overlay"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_rounded_rectangle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_backdrop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_backdrop"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_backdrop"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_backdrop"/>
```

In ConstraintLayout you could set view bounds to other view.